# Can't get proper internet connection status on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS project, I want to know if a user is connected to the internet or not.

Here is what I did:

```swift
import Network

final class NetworkHelper
{
    static let instance = NetworkHelper()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
    private let monitor: NWPathMonitor = NWPathMonitor()
    public private(set) var connected: Bool = false
    
    
    public func startMonitoring()
    {
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            
            self?.connected = path.status == .satisfied
        }
    }
}
```

then, I start listening to network status changes in `AppDelegate`:

```swift
override func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
    NetworkHelper.instance.startMonitoring()
}
```

and everytime I need to know if the user is connected or not, I read the value of:

```swift
NetworlHelper.instance.connected
```

Since I don't have any iPhone or iPad with me, I tested that with an iOS emulator, turning on and off the wifi connection of my MacBook.

But for some reason, here is what happens:

- I launch the app and read the value of `NetworlHelper.instance.connected` with an available connection on my MacBook, I get: `true`
- then I turn off the wifi, I still get `true`
- then I turn on the wifi again, now I get `false`

It's like it's an event late or something.

Did I do something wrong, or is it some weird behavior with the emulator?

Thanks.

Comment: The simulator isn't reliable for this kind of testing

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh ok, that's why. Thanks!